# Create 10 min resolution grid in R

Tags: r, grid, spatial

I would like to create a global 10 minute resolution grid in R to overlay some point occurrences and then subset these by each grid cell.

I have the following GRIDFILE file:

```
gridtype=lonlat
xsize=2160
ysize=900
xfirst=-179.916672
xinc=0.16666666666666667
yfirst=81.9166664
yinc=-0.16666666666666667
10mingrid.gridfile (END)
```

Is there a way to reproduce this as a SpatialGrid in R as I haven't been able to read it in using the sp package?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try to read with `sp`?

Comment: What's the definition of that file? Does `xfirst` and `yfirst` refer to cell centres? It should just be a matter of simple arithmetic: `xfirst + (0:(xsize-1)) * xinc` and so forth. See also the `raster` package.

Comment: I think xfirst and yfirst refer to the starting values for x and y, i.e. -179.92 longitude, 81.9 latitude

Comment: Yes, but if its a grid sometimes these values are the **edges** of the grid and sometimes the **centres** of the grid cell. It makes a difference.

Comment: Also I see you have ysize=900 and yinc=1/6, which gives you 150 degrees of latitude. So its not a global grid. Is that what you want? A grid from +82 to -68?

Comment: Yep that's right as it matches the environmental data I am working with. I am now trying to create a grid using:

Comment: r = raster(nrows=900, ncols=2160, xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-60, ymx=90)